# Scrape attribute value using XPATH?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I just started using XPath for html scraping, so I am a little confused with the syntax. I am trying to extract the url from the following snippet of the sourse code:

```
  <a href="/realestateandhomes-detail/15645-SW-74th-Circle-Dr-Apt-5_Miami_FL_33193_M69309-37779">
      <img alt="15645 Sw 74th Circle Dr Apt 5, Miami, FL 33193" title="15645 Sw 74th Circle Dr Apt 5, Miami, FL 33193" class="js-srp-listing-photos" itemprop="image" data-src="https://ap.rdcpix.com/1980533383/49e7a93da461352c04b8e7146a8d2ceel-m0xd-w480_h480_q80.jpg" data-omtag="srp-listMap:result:photo" src="https://ap.rdcpix.com/1980533383/49e7a93da461352c04b8e7146a8d2ceel-m0xd-w480_h480_q80.jpg" />
  </a>
```

the html path is as follows :

```
<body> 
  <li>
    <div>
      <a></a>
```

I am using scrapy to parse the html page and this is my code so far:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from realtor.items import RealtorItem
class RealtorSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "realtor"
    allowed_domains = ["realtor.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Miami_FL"
        ]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//li/div/a/@href')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = RealtorItem()
            item['link'] = site.select('div/a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

when i run the code it returns an error at line 16 i.e the item[] = site.select().extract(). I am not sure if the syntax is right or there is another underlying problem I am missing.

the error is

```
KeyError: 'RealtorItem does not supprot field: link'
```

my items.py code is as follows :

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class RealtorItem(Item):
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: What's the version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: it is scrapy v 1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to extract the `href` attribute using this selector `//li/div/a/@href` and then iterate through each of the extracted elements but what you are actually doing in fetching the extracted text in the `href` attribute which doesn't fetch anything when using the `//li/div/a/@href` selector again.

Here's a fix implemented in the newer version of scrapy for your Spider class

```
import scrapy

class RealtorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "realtor"
    allowed_domains = ["realtor.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Miami_FL"
        ]
    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//li/div/a') # <----- fetches all the <a> tags
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            print(site.extract())
            item = RealtorItem()
            item['link'] = site.xpath('@href').extract() # <--- extract value from a tag
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Here's the `items.py` file

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class RealtorItem(Item):
    link = Field()
```

*Totally Unrelated Advise:* This has nothing to do with your code but you are using some functions in scrapy that are deprecated. You should go through the [scrapy tutorial](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) in order to learn how to get started using the newer version of scrapy.

Comment: i tried changing the code and it still gives me the same error : {KeyError: 'RealtorItem does not support field: link'} is it a problem with my item.py file does it also have deprecated functions ?

Comment: Yes. I will update my code with the `items.py` file I have.